# Connect Two networks via Router, so an IP intercom(door phone) and communicate

Tags: networking, router

I'm installing an IP intercom door phone. I need that intercom to be able to communicate between two different networks because I have tenants on two different levels with separate networks.
    1   The networks are Network1 (17.148.17.x) and Network2(10.1.10.x)
    2   The router is an EdgeMax-x
    3   I've bridged them on the router and I’m able to ping from a 17.148.17.x to a 10.1.10.x, but I'm not sure how to get rid of the DHCP because I don't want people getting IP addresses from Network1 if they're on Network2
    4   I'm kind of tech-savvy but I haven't dealt with connecting two networks in a while
I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is this router the "default gateway" for devices of both networks, or is there another router somewhere that acts as the default gateway?

Comment: No it’s not, this is something I’m adding in. Between both networks

Comment: Do you have admin access to the current default gateway(s) of both networks? (Do they share the same router?)

Comment: I would have to talk with each IT department to get admin access for that. Is there away to get around that?

Comment: There might be, if you can specify custom configuration on _all_ hosts (the IP phone and so on) that will be involved in the communication. Other than that, no. (And make sure you have IT depts' approval to connect the networks without getting fired...)

Comment: Hmmm ok, I can specify the IP address, subnet and gateway on the IP door intercom. I was thinking if static coding the ports on this router I’m installing but I don’t think that will work. The switch has 5 ports, eth0-4, I’ve bridges ports eth1-3 and im able to ping from 17.148.17.x to 10.1.10.x but I guess the main issue is that DHCP problem which I herd i have to look into the DHCP relay agent and I just have to make sure the intercom (when a contact is pressed) it can dial to any phone On either network via SIP